# difference between dictionary and hybrid dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

what are the difference between dictionary and hybrid dictionary?
twice take a key and value, and which is preferable according to performance?

Hybrid Dictionary:

```
Dim myCol As New HybridDictionary()
myCol.Add("Braeburn Apples", "1.49")
```

Dictionary:

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
dictionary.Add("Dot", 20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HybridDictionary` uses a `ListDictionary` when the set is small and a `Hashtable` when the set is large.

It's in general more performant than a `Dictionary` (at least when there are less than 10 items, otherwise it should be almost identical), however there's a hit when the collection changes from `List` to `Hashtable` (when you go over 10 items the list has to be copied to the hashtable).

The recommended usage for `HybridDictionary` (vs a normal `Dictionary`) is when the collection will be small most of the time (again, <10 items as per the current implementation), but there's a possibility that it'll grow large.

As in usage (compared to `ListDictionary` or `HashTable`), since `Dictionary` uses generics), there's no difference, it's just a performance thing.

My recommendation: don't use `HybridDictionary` at all unless there's a specific need for it.

Since it doesn't use generics, as @adrianm points out in the comments, if using value types, it'll cause boxing and unboxing, which come at a performance cost.

And since it's only a tiny bit faster for less than 10 items, and 10 items should never be a big performance hit even on a `Hashtable`... unless there's something **really** critical, there's no need to use it at all.

Comment: Since a HybridDictionary will cause a lot of boxing/unboxing for value types I would assume a generic dictionary is faster also for small collections containing value types. See no need to use a HybridDictionary in new code on platforms supporting generics.

Comment: @adrianm that's absolutely right too. I'll add it to the answer